# Android Calling Service Method without instance

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, android-service

I have a Connection Class thats receiving callback from native code. As soon as a callback arrives a message object is getting build.

I have a service that is supposed to send this message to other applications.

My connection  class looks like this:

```
//Callback from the native code
public void callback(int data1, int data2){
buildMsg(int data1, int data2);
}

public void buildMsg(int data1, int data2){
Message msg = new Message(data1,data2);
}
```

The message object is parcelable.

The buildMsg method should call the newMsgReceived() Method, to make the service send this message other applications.

The Service looks like this:

```
public void newMsgReceived(Message msg){
//calling an interface for IPC to send the message
}
```

This Service is getting started from the message-receiving application so all the binding and ipc allready works. So my problem is, isit possible to call the method newMsgReceived() when the native callback arrives, without creating another instance of the service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Service class, add

```
static private Service _singletonInstance = null;

private void setInstance() { _singletonInstance = this; }

private static void newMsgReceived(Message msg) { _singletonInstance.newMsgReceived(msg); }
```

*error-checking not included for brevity*